# Android Architecture Components: After screen rotation, fragment is called twice

Tags: android, android-fragments, oncreate, screen-rotation, model-view

I try to understand the Android ViewModel and I am facing at a strange behaviour:

Everything is OK when I launch the app, but on each rotation the fragment ( onCreateView..., onCreate...) is called twice.

I use a ModelView to instantiate the Fragment in the Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String TAG="main";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: mainactivity");
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        MyModelView viewModel =  ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyModelView.class);

        viewModel.getmCurrentStep().observe(this,(MyStepModel step) -> {

            if (step != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: step "+step.getmFragment());

            getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.fragmentLayout, step.createFragment())
                            .commit();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The Fragment:

```
public class FragmentPrincipal extends Fragment {
    String TAG="main";
    public FragmentPrincipal() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView:fragment1 ");
       return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_principal, container, false);
    }
}
```

ViewModel: Nothing particular I follow tutorials on web (Thank you for all who has written them !!!)

```
public class MyModelView extends ViewModel {                   
    private MutableLiveData<MyStepModel> mCurrentStep=new MutableLiveData<>();

    public MyModelView() {
        mCurrentStep.setValue(MyStepModel.FRAGMENT1);
    }

    public MutableLiveData<MyStepModel> getmCurrentStep() {
        return mCurrentStep;
    }

    //public void toFragment1(){
    //  mCurrentStep.setValue(MyStepModel.FRAGMENT1);
    //}
}

public enum  MyStepModel {
    FRAGMENT1(FragmentPrincipal.class),
    FRAGMENT2(FragmentSecond.class);

    public Class<? extends Fragment> getmFragment() {
        return mFragment;
    }

    private final Class<? extends Fragment> mFragment;

    MyStepModel(Class<? extends Fragment> fragmentClass) {
        mFragment =fragmentClass;
    }

    public  Fragment createFragment(){
       String TAG ="main";
       Log.i(TAG, "createFragment:mystepmodel ");
       try {
           return mFragment.newInstance();
       } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
       }
   }
}
```

I'm open to any suggestion. Have I missed something? What?

Comment: activity will be recreated when you rotate the phone. so onCreate will be called again. I think its not so strange

Comment: but it's called 2 time during  rotation. To be clear, during one cycle , onCreateView is called 2 time. and in the fragment manager , the fragment is replaced two times .

Comment: For example ,if you have some data in onSaveInstanceStat , during rotation your SaveInstanceStat  bundle becomes null. due to second call to oncreate

Comment: Right. I think its because the onChanged method get called twice. Have you tried using ``SingleLiveEvent`` https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java

Comment: What is toFragment() doing,  I strongly believe it is due to the observable and live data

Comment: I m going to try, as soon i understand the function  :)   thank you Emil !

Comment: @lib4 sure it is . The toFragment() is just  to call Fragment from another no need for this example.

Comment: Solution :I used savedInstanceState==null . And for other test with several fragments: in Class Fragment , i put all observer in the OnCreate methode.